# How to retrive the values from html and print it using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**This is my html code I want a *javascript* to get the values from the text box and *print it on the same page***

```
<body>
<header>
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
</header>
<form name="myform" method="post" action="#"><table align="center"><tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fn" id="fn" required="required"/></td></tr><tr>
<td>last Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="ln" id="ln" required="required"/></td></tr><tr>
<td>DOB</td>
<td><input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" required="required"/></td></tr><tr>
<td>Description</td>
<td><textarea name="fn" cols="16" rows="5" id="txt" required="required"></textarea></td></tr><tr>
<td><input type="button" value="submit" onclick="validate()" /></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
    </form> 
   </body>
 </html>
```

I tired to print it in the table form using the javascript displayed below .. It is not working can u suggest some other code

```
        val = ''
        val += 'First Name: '.append("<tr><td>" + document.getElementById('fn').value + "</td></tr></br>");
        val += 'Last Name: ' .append("<tr><td>" +document.getElementById('ln').value + "</td></tr></br>");
        + '<br>';
        val += 'DOB:  ' + document.getElementById('dob').value + '<br>';
        val += 'Description: ' + document.getElementById('txt').value + '<br>';
        divprint = document.createElement('div')
        divprint.innerHTML = val; document.body.appendChild(divprint)
```

Comment: You have NO javascript in your question (except for a call to a function)... Show us what you have tried, what you expected, and what didn't work...  we will not do it for you, but can help where you get stuck.

Comment: Also, I can't resist saying that table-based layouts are "so-last-millenium"

Comment: Please explain..when you want to get the text values and print

Comment: @RonniSkansing Definitely not even close to the same problem. I certainly hope you didn't flag this as a duplicate.

Comment: where you want to print the values in your HTML.. I will show them in table format

Comment: K.K.Agarwal I want to get the values from the text boxes and display it on the same page in table format using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ...

Create  a div and append it into Body and place the Values in that div..

```
     function validate() {
      val = ''
            val += document.getElementById('fn').value +'<br>';
           val += document.getElementById('ln').value +'<br>';
        val += document.getElementById('dob').value +'<br>';
             val += document.getElementById('txt').value +'<br>';
     divprint = document.createElement('div')
divprint.innerHTML = val;

document.body.appendChild(divprint)

        }
```

USe this for table format

```
    val = ''
                    val = "<tr><td>first Name: " + document.getElementById('fn').value +'</td></tr>';
                   val += "<tr><td>Last Name: " +document.getElementById('ln').value +'</td></tr>';
                val += "<tr><td>DOB: " +document.getElementById('dob').value +'</td></tr>';
                     val += "<tr><td>Description: " +document.getElementById('txt').value +'</td></tr>';
             divprint = document.createElement('table')
        divprint.innerHTML = val;
   // divprint.style.border = '1px solid black';
 divprint.border = '1';


        document.body.appendChild(divprint)
```

Comment: `document.write` is bad practice.

Comment: @K.K.Agarwal I am editing it in Visualstudio and it is showing error in this code

Comment: document.body.appendChild(divprint).. do it by replacing or just add document before body

Comment: in document.getElementById(..) it is showing expected ";"

Comment: @K.K.Agarwal Can I get the values printed in a table form

Comment: @K.K.Agarwal I tried appending the html code in JS but it is not working can you update the code

Comment: I have modified the code for adding style in the table

Comment: can I get lines for rows and columns too , only the border appears

Comment: modified ..just check..is it okay...if not please use css

Answer (score 1):

```
// grab a reference to the HTML input element
var elem = document.getElementById('fn');

// Retrieve its value (contained text)
var fnValue = elem.value;

// Print on the page
document.write(fnValue)
```

**UPDATE**

For other fields is similar to the above code:

```
var elemLn = document.getElementById('ln');
var LnValue = elemLn.value;
document.write('<br/>' + LnValue);

var elemDob = document.getElementById('dob');
var DobValue = elemDob.value;
document.write('<br/>' + DobValue);
```

Comment: `document.write` is bad practice.

Comment: @GAEfan I'm agree with you, but the question owner wants such a function

Comment: @GAEfan Seems he wants this function for debug purposes!

Comment: @ABFORCE I cant use this code to print all the elements ! it works only for one

Comment: @HareneRangarajan sorry, I'm messed up JS with C, replace `\n` with `<br/>`

Comment: @ABFORCE it is still not working ..@K.K.Agarwal code is working well

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script before the `</body>` tag

```
<script>

    function validate() {
        return document.getElementById('txt').value;
        // or do something with the value...
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this right after `</form>`

```
<div id="emptyDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(){
        document.getElementById("emptyDiv").innerText = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    }
</script>
```

or the function can have:

```
document.getElementById("emptyDiv").innerText = document.myform.fn.value;
```